# solid color to sprite (javascript game)

Tags: javascript, sprites

Hi I recently created a javascript game, in this game, math random is used to pick a random shape.

The shapes are in strings, and the associated numbers within the string are then used to show a color.

Is there any way to replace the simple hex colors with an image?

For example:

```
else if (shape === "H"){
    return [[8,8,8],
            [8,8,8],
            [8,8,8]];
```

The "8" ties into the following string to get the #F10B38 color.

```
const color = [null,"#FF2D00","#FF9300","#51FF00","#00FF93","#0087FF","#4E49A7","#9649A7","#F10B38"];
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Is the return value in that first code snippet supposed to be a 3x3 bitmap where all 9 pixels are the color 8 (#F10B38)? Why not just load sprites as images?

Comment: yes so its a tetris style game, and the 3x3 block is now just a solid color. I was trying to change that from being a solid color to being an image, or maybe something a bit more stylish than a simple solid color

Comment: So what you actually want to ask is how to use images in Javascript? Are you using canvas or DOM to visualize your game?